# Forms elements don't insert with the correct jquery mobile design

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I built a form using jquery.
As soon as I use $('#Form').append(''); the newly added elements aren't themed / don't look the same way as I they would, when I insert them using PHP.

To make it clear:

php added: Jquery Mobile Style

Jquery dynamicly added: Regular Form style.

How can I buy pass this?

======ADDON======
Ok, here's the code

this functions adds the block:

```
function addItem(section){
    if(itemcounter[section]>1){
        $('table#deductionItemContent'+section+' tr:last').after('<tr id="deductionItemContentRow'+section+'_'+itemcounter[section]+'1"></tr>');
        $('table#deductionItemContent'+section+' tr:last').after('<tr id="deductionItemContentRow'+section+'_'+itemcounter[section]+'2"></tr>');
        $('table#deductionItemContent'+section+' tr:last').after('<tr id="deductionItemContentRow'+section+'_'+itemcounter[section]+'3"></tr>');
    }else{
        $('#deductionItemContent'+section).append('<tr id="deductionItemContentRow'+section+'_'+itemcounter[section]+'1"></tr>');
        $('#deductionItemContent'+section).append('<tr id="deductionItemContentRow'+section+'_'+itemcounter[section]+'2"></tr>');
        $('#deductionItemContent'+section).append('<tr id="deductionItemContentRow'+section+'_'+itemcounter[section]+'3"></tr>');
    }

    $('#deductionItemContent'+section).append('<tr id="deductionItemContentRow'+section+'_'+itemcounter[section]+'1"></tr>');
    $('#deductionItemContent'+section).append('<tr id="deductionItemContentRow'+section+'_'+itemcounter[section]+'2"></tr>');
    $('#deductionItemContent'+section).append('<tr id="deductionItemContentRow'+section+'_'+itemcounter[section]+'3"></tr>');
    $('#deductionItemContentRow'+section+'_'+itemcounter[section]+'1').append('<td id="deductionItemContent'+section+'El'+itemcounter[section]+'"></td>');
    $('#deductionItemContent'+section+'El'+itemcounter[section]).append('<div class="type-select"><label for="nu_item_'+section+'_'+itemcounter[section]+'">{/literal}{translate text="application_reports_plate5_item"}{literal}'+itemcounter[section]+'</label><select onchange="updateForm('+section+');" id="nu_item_'+section+'_'+itemcounter[section]+'" name="nu_item_'+section+'_'+itemcounter[section]+'"></select></div>')
    $('#nu_item_'+section+'_'+itemcounter[section]).append('<option value="main">{/literal}{translate text="application_reports_plate5_item_main"}{literal}</option>');
    $('#nu_item_'+section+'_'+itemcounter[section]).append('<option value="aux">{/literal}{translate text="application_reports_plate5_item_aux"}{literal}</option>');
    $('#nu_item_'+section+'_'+itemcounter[section]).append('<option value="jib">{/literal}{translate text="application_reports_plate5_jib"}{literal}</option>');
    $('#nu_item_'+section+'_'+itemcounter[section]).append('<option value="rope">{/literal}{translate text="application_reports_plate5_rope"}{literal}</option>');
    $('#nu_item_'+section+'_'+itemcounter[section]).append('<option value="underhookdevice">{/literal}{translate text="application_reports_plate5_underhookdevice"}{literal}</option>');
    $('#nu_item_'+section+'_'+itemcounter[section]).append('<option value="rigging">{/literal}{translate text="application_reports_plate5_rigging"}{literal}</option>');
    $('#nu_item_'+section+'_'+itemcounter[section]).append('<option value="none">{/literal}{translate text="application_reports_plate5_none"}{literal}</option>');
    $('#deductionItemContentRow'+section+'_'+itemcounter[section]+'2').append('<td id="deductionItemContent'+section+'E2'+itemcounter[section]+'"></td>');
    $('#deductionItemContent'+section+'E2'+itemcounter[section]).append('<div class="type-select"><label for="nu_status_'+section+'_'+itemcounter[section]+'">{/literal}{translate text="application_reports_plate5_itemstatus"}{literal} '+'</label><select onchange="updateForm('+section+');" id="nu_status_'+section+'_'+itemcounter[section]+'" name="nu_status_'+section+'_'+itemcounter[section]+'"></select></div>')
    $('#nu_status_'+section+'_'+itemcounter[section]).append('<option value="stowed">{/literal}{translate text="application_reports_plate5_item_stowed"}{literal}</option>');
    $('#nu_status_'+section+'_'+itemcounter[section]).append('<option value="erected">{/literal}{translate text="application_reports_plate5_item_erected"}{literal}</option>');
    $('#nu_status_'+section+'_'+itemcounter[section]).append('<option value="inservice">{/literal}{translate text="application_reports_plate5_item_inservice"}{literal}</option>');
    $('#nu_status_'+section+'_'+itemcounter[section]).append('<option value="none">{/literal}{translate text="application_reports_plate5_none"}{literal}</option>');
    $('#deductionItemContentRow'+section+'_'+itemcounter[section]+'3').append('<td id="deductionItemContent'+section+'E3'+itemcounter[section]+'"></td>');
    $('#deductionItemContent'+section+'E3'+itemcounter[section]).append('<div class="type-text"><label for="nu_deduction_'+section+'_'+itemcounter[section]+'">{/literal}{translate text="application_reports_plate5_deduction"}{literal}</label><input onkeyup="updateForm('+section+');" type="text" length="6" maxlength="6" id="nu_deduction_'+section+'_'+itemcounter[section]+'" name="nu_deduction_'+section+'_'+itemcounter[section]+'" /></div>');
    /**
     * Add Data to page 3
     */
    $('#weightMasterDataTable'+section).append('<tr id="weightMasterDataTableRow'+section+itemcounter[section]+'"></tr>');
    $('#weightMasterDataTableRow'+section+itemcounter[section]).append('<td id="weightMasterDataTableContent'+section+itemcounter[section]+'1"></td>');
    $('#weightMasterDataTableRow'+section+itemcounter[section]).append('<td id="weightMasterDataTableContent'+section+itemcounter[section]+'2"></td>');
    $('#weightMasterDataTableRow'+section+itemcounter[section]).append('<td id="weightMasterDataTableContent'+section+itemcounter[section]+'3">0</td>');
    $('#weightMasterDataTableRow'+section+itemcounter[section]).append('<td id="weightMasterDataTableContent'+section+itemcounter[section]+'4">0</td>');
    $('#weightMasterDataTableRow'+section+itemcounter[section]).append('<td id="weightMasterDataTableContent'+section+itemcounter[section]+'5">0</td>');
    /**
     * Add Radio Buttons
     */
    $('#weightMasterDataButtons'+section).append('<input type="radio" name="nu_masterbutton_'+section+'" id="nu_masterbutton_'+section+'_'+itemcounter[section]+'" value="'+itemcounter[section]+'" /><label for="nu_masterbutton_'+section+'_'+itemcounter[section]+'" >&nbsp;&nbsp;{/literal}{translate text="application_reports_plate5_item"}{literal} '+itemcounter[section]+'</label>');
    $('#weightMasterDataButtons'+section).append('<br />');
    /**
     * in the end update counter
     */
    itemcounter[section]++;
}
```

the HTML code that belongs to this looks like this:

```
<tr>
    <td>
        <div id="tabs-2">
            <h4>deductions for loadtest 1</h4>
            <div id="deductions1">
                <a onclick="addItem(1);">+ Add item to deduction</a>
                <table id="deductionMaster1" class="tablecloth" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr id="deductionMasterRow11">
                            <td>
                                <table id="deductionItemContent1" class="tablecloth" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0"></table>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr id="deductionMasterRow12">
                            <td id="deductionMasterElement12">
                            total:
                            <b id="deductionValue1">0</b>
                            lbs
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

This is only a small part of the form, because everything reacts the same way.
I guess I need to tell the browser somewho that the inserted form elements are to be themed the jquery style.
But I don't know how to.

Comment: While I'm sure that you are sure that your code is correct, post it here so we won't have to look into a million possible problems trying to give you an answer

Comment: I know I took a little bit complicated way, but this is only the first version. I have to redo a lot of stuff, but first I need it in a working state^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding

```
$('select').selectmenu();
```

at the end of the jQuery script. That should deal with the <select> tags.
If that is successful, refer to jquery mobile's documentation for information on how to deal with any other form element you want on you page.

Comment: thanks that helped a lot.
The only parts that I could not transform are the input fields.
I set the class to work around it.